# Chrome Extension: Make Dom Changes Made By Content Script Keep Persistant On The Extension Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ok so this is the first time I'm developing a Chrome extension so I'm sorry if i'm asking for obvious things. What I'm trying to do is to sort a HTML structure of DOM elements with my extension using a content script (I don't know if this is a good practice or I have to put all of that extension logic as a background script).

The extension works and everything but I'm having A LOT of problems trying to make the DOM changes in the popup be persistent after the extension popup is closed. What I'm doing is every-time the user clicks a "SORT" button in the popup the text of that button changes to "STOP SORTING" but as soon as the popup window closes the button goes back to its original state and I don't want that to happen.

**UPDATE:** I'm trying to use chrome storage as suggested in the comments but now I'm getting an "Error handling response: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" when running my background.js. Any help will be really appreciated.

**UPDATE2**: As suggested by wOxxOm I have moved the functions that deal with the chrome storage to the popupFunc.js file but I'm still getting the "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

**UPDATE3**: Changed the popupFunc.js. Now I have just one function 'save_button_state()' doing the set and get data from the Chrome Storage, I then call that function after the onclick event of the popup button. I don't get any console errors and I can log the button text to the right values but when the popup is closed it keeps the same original value before it was clicked.

Here's my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Jorge Páez",
  "description": "Extension Test",
  "short_name": "Chrome Extension Test",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "scripts/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*"],
      "css": ["styles/custom.css"],
      "js": ["scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "scripts/content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon32.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
  "page_action": {
    "default_title": "Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Here's my popup HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>xyz's Zendesk Chrome Extension</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/popupFunc.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>xyz's Zendesk Chrome Extension</h1>
        <h2>Current Functions:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Add Toggle Bar to SideBar</li>
            <li>Sorting Incoming Chats by Priority Field</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="button" id="js-toggleSorting"><span id="sortingButton">SORT INCOMING CHATS</span></button>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Here's the popup.js: Where I'm passing some parameters to my script file, changing the Popup DOM, etc.

```
function save_button_state() {
  var obj = {};
  obj["sortButtonText"] = $("#sortingButton").text();
  chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function () {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("sortButtonText", function (data) {
      sortButtonText = data.sortButtonText;
      $("#sortingButton").text(sortButtonText);
      console.log("Value from Chrome Storage" + " " + data.sortButtonText);
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  var toggleSorting = document.getElementById("js-toggleSorting");
  var sortFunction = function (goSort) {
    if (goSort) {
      console.log("Starting the Sorting Function");
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "goSort=true;" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "scripts/sortChatQueue.js" });
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Stopping The Sorting");
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "goSort=false;" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "scripts/sortChatQueue.js" });
      });
    }
  };
  $(toggleSorting).on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("data-click-state") == 1) {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 0);
      $(this).find("span").html("SORT INCOMING CHATS");
      sortFunction(false);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 1);
      $(this).find("span").html("STOP SORTING INCOMING CHATS");
      sortFunction(true);
    }
    save_button_state();
  });
});
```

And here's the background.js:

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
    {
      conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: {
            hostEquals: "URL",
            schemes: ["https"],
          },
        }),
      ],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()],
    },
  ]);
});
```

Comment: The popup is created anew each time it's shown and destroyed when hidden. Basically it's just like any other page you open in a browser. You need to save/restore the state in `chrome.storage` or in `localStorage`, look for examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @wOxxOm. I just made an update on my original question. I'm trying to use chrome storage but I guess there's some diference on data structures between the dom element I'm trying to save inside the chrome.storage.sync.get that is causing me trouble.

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page, which is not related to the popup page. All code that deals with the popup's DOM should run in popupFunc.js

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I just did that (check Update 2 in my original question) but I still get the same error. I'm pretty sure the problem is that I'm trying to pass an incorrect data structure to the data object I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `.text() = item.sortedButtonStatus` should be `.text(item.sortedButtonStatus)`, next time simply google for something like "setting text in jquery" and you'll see a lot of examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm gettting everything right except that when i close the popup it won't get me the new text value in the button so even if I clicked before I'm still getting "Sort Incoming Chats" as the button text. I'm sorry I'm a total newbie with the Chrome Extension and API, really appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to move the entire chrome.storage.sync.get call into ready() callback to *actually read the storage* .

Comment: I have moved the whole 'save_button_state' function inside the ready() but still doesn't work. Can you develop please ? Also, I'm calling the function inside the ready() that's why I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: There's no need to *save* the data at the start. You need to *read* the data, which is done by calling chrome.storage.sync.get so you need to call it right away inside ready() callback.

Comment: Still not working sorry I guess I will need your code changes because I really don't get it.

Comment: I thought this is something trivial so evidently it's not. Ask a new question please.

Comment: Just made a new question, thanks a lot @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem this way:

```
function save_button_state() {
  buttonStateText = $("#sortingButton").html();
  buttonStateAttribute = $("#sortingButton").attr("data-click-state");
  chrome.storage.local.set(
    {
      buttonStateText: buttonStateText,
      buttonStateAttribute: buttonStateAttribute,
    },
    function () {
      console.log(
        "Saved State" +
          " " +
          buttonStateText +
          " " +
          "Saved Attribute" +
          " " +
          buttonStateAttribute
      );
    }
  );
}
function get_button_state() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(
    ["buttonStateText", "buttonStateAttribute"],
    function (data) {
      $("#sortingButton").html(data.buttonStateText);
      $("#sortingButton").attr("data-click-state", data.buttonStateAttribute);
      console.log(
        "Get State" +
          " " +
          data.buttonStateText +
          " " +
          "Get Attribute" +
          " " +
          data.buttonStateAttribute
      );
    }
  );
}
$(document).ready(() => {
  get_button_state();
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
  });
  var sortFunction = function (goSort) {
    if (goSort) {
      console.log("Starting the Sorting Function");
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "goSort=true;" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "scripts/sortChatQueue.js" });
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Stopping The Sorting");
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "goSort=false;" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "scripts/sortChatQueue.js" });
      });
    }
  };
  $("#sortingButton").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).attr("data-click-state") == 1) {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 0);
      $(this).html("SORT INCOMING CHATS");
      sortFunction(false);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 1);
      $(this).html("STOP SORTING INCOMING CHATS");
      sortFunction(true);
    }
    save_button_state();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add "storage" permission on extensions manifest file and store the button status on chrome.storage.local with some keys. Then you need to check the value in the chrome storage each time when you open the popup.

for more reference: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage